# Rename for Laravel 5 Storage

Tags: laravel-5

Is there a rename method for Laravel 5's [Filesystem](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem)? I looked in the API and in the documentation, could not find it. I am trying to rename a directory, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I would have thought the `move()` method would do it? I’d expect it to work on both files and directories.

Comment: @MartinBean For sure, but we need to let Laravel know where it is :)

Comment: I will try Storage::move(). But it seems odd that FlySystem api shows a rename method, but laravel chose not to use it?

Comment: @MartinBean, please submit as answer. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [move()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_move) method will work on both files and directories.

Comment: I think you meant move()

Comment: @JasonSpick I did. Sorry!